# Fontawesome: how to use completely in local?

Tags: font-awesome

I'd like to use fontawesome in a closed net environment.
So we can't access CDN.

I know I can simply download the css, but where are the font files?

CSS actually point to this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
}
```

Is it possible to downlaod and use .eot / woff / ttf / svg locally ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the last version of [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

You will download a .zip with all you are looking for in the fonts folder

```
font-awesome-4.1.0
 - fonts 
   + FontAwesome.otf
   + fontawesome-webfont.eot
   + fontawesome-webfont.svg
   + fontawesome-webfont.ttf
   + fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

EDIT : If you look correctly in the variables.less and path.less files you will see that the font are grab at the url `"../fonts/fontawesome.xxx"`

Comment: This works !I expanded your solution using fontawesome as a git submodule.

Comment: That link is dead, please update :-)

Comment: @bk138 FontAwesome made a lot of changes over the years, especially on the licenses and the packaging structure so this approach won't work anymore. Here is their site if you want to download their latest version https://fontawesome.com/download